# Variable declaration as side-effect

Tags: c++, c, gcc, comma-operator

So I'm looking over C++ operator rules as I do when my programs start behaving wonkily. And I come across the comma operator. Now, I have known it was there for a while but never used it, so I began reading, and I come across this little gem:

```
if (int y = f(x), y > x)
{
    // statements that use y
}
```

I had never thought about using commas' first arguments' side-effects to get locally-scoped variables without the need for bulky block-delimited code or repeated function calls. Naturally, this all excited me greatly, and I immediately ran off to try it.

```
test_comma.cpp: In function 'int main()':
test_comma.cpp:9:18: error: expected ')' before ',' token
  if (int y = f(x), y > x) {
```

I tried this on both a C and C++ compiler, and neither of them liked it. I tried instead declaring `y` in the outer scope, and it compiled and ran just fine without the `int` in the `if` condition, but that defeats the purpose of the comma here. Is this just a GCC implementation quirk? The opinion of the Internet seems to be that this should be perfectly valid C (and ostensibly, to my eye, C++) code; there is no mention of this error on any GCC or C++ forum that I've seen.

---

EDIT: Some more information. I am using MinGW GCC 4.8.1-4 on Windows 7 64-bit (though obviously my binaries are 32-bit; I need to install mingw-w64 one of these days).

I also tried using this trick outside of a conditional statement, as below:

```
int y = (int z = 5, z);
```

This threw up two different errors:

```
test_comma.cpp: In function 'int main()':
test_comma.cpp:9:11: error: expected primary-expression before 'int'
      int y = (int z = 5, z);
       ^
test_comma.cpp:9:11: error: expected ')' before 'int'
```

With creative use of parentheses in my `if` statement above, I managed to get the same errors there, too.

Answer (score 4):

Contrary to what several other people have claimed, [declarations inside the `if` conditional are perfectly valid](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/334c28d8aadf6a27). However, your code is not.

The first problem is that you're not actually using the comma operator, but [almost] attempting to declare multiple variables. [*That* is not valid in an `if` conditional](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/b3e64c2f0caf157f). And, even if it *were* possible, your second declaration would be entirely broken anyway since you try to redeclare `y`, and you do so with `>` instead of `=`. It all simply makes no sense.

The following code is sort of similar:

```
if (int y = (f(x), y > x))
```

Now [at least it's *half*-valid](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/2e04b4efa52e0112), but you're using `y` uninitialised and yielding undefined behaviour.

**Declarations and expressions are not the same thing**, so the following is quite different code:

```
int y = 0;
if (y = f(x), y > x)
```

Now you don't have a problem with uninitialised variables, either (because I initialised `y` myself), and you're getting this "side-effect declaration" that doesn't change the resulting value of the `if` conditional. But it's about as clear as mud. Look how the precedence forms:

```
int y = 0;
if ((y = f(x)), (y > x))
```

That's not really very intuitive.

Hopefully this total catastrophe has been a lesson in avoiding this sort of cryptic code in entirety. :)

Comment: @haccks: [Ill-formed](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/e2d0725e57315723); my second paragraph applies here.

Comment: I misunderstand. Of course `,` is not comma operator here :).

Answer (score 1):

You cannot declare variable and apply `operator ,` simultaneously either you are declaring variable (in case of `if` it would be only one 'cause result needs to be resolved to `bool`), either you are writing some statement (also resolving to `bool`) which may include `operator ,` in it.

Answer (score 0):

You need to declare y on the top of if condition:

int y;

if(y=f(x),y>x)

{

}

This will check the last condition defined in the if condition and rest others are executed as general statements.